# How to ensure the encrypted length are same as the given string

Tags: java, encryption

Hi is it possible to encrypt the string with the certain length that i want? for example: i want to encrypt this string `BI000001` to something like hex value `A3D5F2ARD3`(random) fixed it at 10 length. Therefore when user enter this value `A3D5F2ARD3`, system will based on this value and decrypt it to get back the value `BI000001` .

is it possible to do this in java?

I tried a lot of method but all encrypted length are way too long.

Comment: Why is it important that the encrypted data is the same length as the unencrypted data?

Comment: The hex value is shorter that your plaintext (assuming binary encoding). So no that's not possible.

Comment: What ciphertext encoding do expect where the 10 character/byte limit holds? How long are your plaintexts and which characterset do you allow?

Comment: There are limits to the density of information in any set.  Compression algorithms are designed to maximize this density within reason.  Encryption algorithms are not.  Typically, an encrypted set of data will contain exactly as many bytes as the plain text with padding.  If you want the cipher text smaller than the plain text, compress the plain text before encrypting.  Compressing to a set small fixed length is impossible.  You can hash to a set small fixed length, but hashing is not reversible.

Comment: my plaintexts are fixed at 10 length... i need to encrypted them with customize length (like 8/9/10 not too long like normal encryption value)... i know it's not possible for encryption algorithms. But is there any other way i can perform this ?

Comment: It seems you need format-preserving encryption. Some algorithms are patented, so be careful what you implement. If you're not that security conscious, you can use a classical cipher like [Vigènere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+vigenere) with a big enough alphabet.

Comment: Noted with thanks. @ArtjomB.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any JDK built-in Java encryption method which provides this feature. Then again, I am not an encryption expert, but I guess such a custom feature won't be built in the JDK. 
Maybe this discussion is also useful: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6098/is-there-a-length-preserving-encryption-scheme

Why do you want to preserve size of the string? maybe there is another solution for your problem.

Comment: Java lacks this functionality because it is literally impossible to implement lossless compression to a length of 10 for almost any set that is much larger than 10.  True there are special cases.  A very long string of '1' can be compressed into a '1' and a number indicating repetitions.  But for more complicated sets, compressing (encrypted or not) to length 10 without loss of information may be impossible.

Comment: well OP is not asking for compression, but encryption. Sure if the goal is to map an arbitrary string to a same-sized hex string, it is not possible

Comment: Um, if encryption algorithms is not possible to use. May i know any other methods to perform format preserve encryption? i have a fixed length at 10 for my string.. i just need to "encode" them to alphanumeric and can be "decode"

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use a [block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) such as AES to encrypt data. Block ciphers (as their name suggest) work in blocks of data of a fixed size, for example AES works in blocks of 128 bits. If a block cipher encounters input smaller than the block size it [pads it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher#Padding), which is likely why you are seeing the ciphertext larger than the plaintext.

If you want to preserve the length then consider Format Preserving Encryption as mentioned in [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/symmetric-encryption-mode-where-ciphertext-size-is-plain-text-size).